# Understanding Neural network backpropagation using matlab

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I am working on backpropagation algorithm.can anyone explain me how do i plot performance graph without using matlab tools.i mean please give me detailed information about performance plot and how do i plot using my input and target set..also explain me what is meant by the goal.
thnx in advance

Comment: Without matlab?  What language do you want to use?  Do you have a programming question?

Comment: i m sorry i have mislead you...without matlab here i meant without using matlab tools...sry for the inconvenience..kindly provide me with a answer...in this i am using matlab only as my programming language..